# Show only 3 lines in <p> tag which contains several <p></p>

Tags: java, html, css, angular

I have p tag which contains several p tags.

Here is html code fetched from back-end

```
<p><p>Hello World1</p><p>Hello World2</p><p>Hello World3</p><p>Hello World4</p><p>Hello World5</p><p>Hello World6</p></p>
```

Right now I really wanna display only few lines.

**But back-end also sometimes return html without p tag.**

Let me know how to resolve this issue.

Now I am working on Angular 6 project.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you retrieving and displaying this html code from your Angular application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `p` tags after fetching html code from back-end and add this css in `p` tag.

Here's solution:

```css
display: -webkit-box;
overflow : hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

*I hope this works for you*.

Comment: If you "remove p tags", how can you "add this css in p tag"? The p tags were removed, so nowhere to add css.

Comment: I can understand what you mean.
so remove p tags once received from backend and then sum up texts, then add one p tag.

Comment: If you remove p tags, how can you identify the "lines"? The content of each inner p tag is a line (paragraph actually), so if you remove p tags, you just end up with one very long line of text.